# Flattening JSON when keys are known only at runtime

Tags: json, swift4, codable, decodable

Let's say we have a JSON structure like the following (commonly used in Firebase's Realtime Database):

```
{
  "18348b9b-9a49-4e04-ac35-37e38a8db1e2": {
    "isActive": false,
    "age": 29,
    "company": "BALOOBA"
  },
  "20aca96e-663a-493c-8e9b-cb7b8272f817": {
    "isActive": false,
    "age": 39,
    "company": "QUONATA"
  },
  "bd0c389b-2736-481a-9cf0-170600d36b6d": {
    "isActive": false,
    "age": 35,
    "company": "EARTHMARK"
  }
}
```

## Expected solution:

Using `Decodable` I'd like to convert it into an array of 3 elements:

```swift
struct BoringEntity: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let isActive: Bool
    let age: Int
    let company: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // ...
    }
}

let entities: [BoringEntity] = try! JSONDecoder()...
```

The **id** attribute corresponds to the json object's root string , e.g: `18348b9b-9a49-4e04-ac35-37e38a8db1e2`.

## Workaround:

I have already tried several approaches but couldn't get the id attribute without requiring an auxiliary entity (or using optionals):

```
/// Incomplete BoringEntity version to make Decodable conformance possible.
struct BoringEntityIncomplete: Decodable {
    let isActive: Bool
    let age: Int
    let company: String
}

// Decode to aux struct
let decoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String : BoringEntityIncomplete].self, for: jsonData)
// Map aux entities to BoringEntity
let entities = decoded.map { BoringEntity(...) }
```

Using `init(from: Decoder)` isn't as trivial as in other cases since `keyedContainer(,)` can't be used due to the fact that the key is unknown.

Is `Decodable` unsuited for these types of cases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base entity:

```
struct BoringEntity: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let isActive: Bool
    let age: Int
    let company: String
}
```

---

## Solution 1: Using an extra struct without the key

```
/// Incomplete BoringEntity version to make Decodable conformance possible.
private struct BoringEntityBare: Decodable {
    let isActive: Bool
    let age: Int
    let company: String
}

// Decode to aux struct
private let decoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String : BoringEntityBare].self, from: jsonData)
// Map aux entities to BoringEntity
let entities = decoded.map { BoringEntity(id: $0.key, isActive: $0.value.isActive, age: $0.value.age, company: $0.value.company) }
print(entities)
```

---

## Solution 2: Using a wrapper

Thanks to Code Different I was able to combine my approach with his `PhantomKeys` idea, but there's no way around it: an extra entity must always be used.

```
struct BoringEntities: Decodable {
    var entities = [BoringEntity]()

    // This really is just a stand-in to make the compiler happy.
    // It doesn't actually do anything.
    private struct PhantomKeys: CodingKey {
        var intValue: Int?
        var stringValue: String
        init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue; self.stringValue = "\(intValue)" }
        init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    }

    private enum BareKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isActive, age, company
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: PhantomKeys.self)

        // There's only one key
        for key in container.allKeys {
            let aux = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: BareKeys.self, forKey: key)

            let age = try aux.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
            let company = try aux.decode(String.self, forKey: .company)
            let isActive = try aux.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isActive)

            let entity = BoringEntity(id: key.stringValue, isActive: isActive, age: age, company: company)
            entities.append(entity)
        }
    }
}

let entities = try JSONDecoder().decode(BoringEntities.self, from: jsonData).entities
print(entities)
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple things before I answer your question:

1: The comment (`// id`) makes the JSON invalid. JSON does not allow comments.

2: Where does the `id` property in `BoringEntity` come from?

```
struct BoringEntity: Decodable {
    let id: String          // where is it stored in the JSON???
    let isActive: Bool
    let age: Int
    let company: String
}
```

---

If I overlook these things, you can wrap the array of `BoringEntity` in a struct (`BoringEntities`). Using `[BoringEntity]` directly is not advisable since you have to overshadow the default `init(from decoder:)` of `Array`.

The trick here is to make `JSONDecoder` gives you back the list of keys via the [`container.allKeys`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2894883-allkeys) property:

```
struct BoringEntity: Decodable {
    let isActive: Bool
    let age: Int
    let company: String
}

struct BoringEntities: Decodable {
    var entities = [BoringEntity]()

    // This really is just a stand-in to make the compiler happy.
    // It doesn't actually do anything.
    private struct PhantomKeys: CodingKey {
        var intValue: Int?
        var stringValue: String 
        init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue; self.stringValue = "\(intValue)" }
        init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: PhantomKeys.self)

        for key in container.allKeys {
            let entity = try container.decode(BoringEntity.self, forKey: key)
            entities.append(entity)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let jsonData = """
{
  "18348b9b-9a49-4e04-ac35-37e38a8db1e2": {
    "isActive": false,
    "age": 29,
    "company": "BALOOBA"
  },
  "20aca96e-663a-493c-8e9b-cb7b8272f817": {
    "isActive": false,
    "age": 39,
    "company": "QUONATA"
  },
  "bd0c389b-2736-481a-9cf0-170600d36b6d": {
    "isActive": false,
    "age": 35,
    "company": "EARTHMARK"
  }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let entities = try JSONDecoder().decode(BoringEntities.self, from: jsonData).entities
```

Comment: I added the comment later to explain where the id attribute came from, knowingly that it would make the json invalid

Comment: So `id` is, for example. `18348b9b-9a49-4e04-ac35-37e38a8db1e2`?

Comment: Indeed. I’ll edit my question to make it clear without invalidating the json sample

Comment: I think you have a good solution already. The only drawback seems to be that you cannot keep the `entities` array in the order that it appears in the JSON.

Comment: Your PhantomKeys struct was a really nice touch. That was the step I was missing