# Swift Decodable JSON dictionary with heterogeneous array

Tags: json, swift4, decodable

I have some JSON that comes back in the following format,

```
{
"Random Word": [
    [
        "2017-08-10",
        6
    ],
    [
        "2017-08-11",
        6
    ],
    [
        "2017-08-15",
        4
    ]
],
"Another Random Word": [
    [
        "2017-08-10",
        4
    ],
    [
        "2017-08-11",
        4
    ],
    [
        "2017-08-12",
        1
    ],
    [
        "2017-08-14",
        2
    ],
    [
        "2017-08-15",
        4
    ],
    [
        "2017-08-16",
        1
    ]
]
}
```

The issue is that the 'key' will be different each time and the 'value' contains a heterogeneous array of Strings (that should be converted to Dates), and Ints.

Is there a way to use Swift's Decodable protocol to turn this into objects?

Here is a Struct that it could be decoded as,

```
struct MyJSONData: Decodable {

    var myInfo: Dictionary<String, [[Any]]>?
    ...
}
```

However, if there is a better way to structure the struct, Im all ears!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use Any/AnyObject. Is your data structure stable ? I mean, will it be always a String and an Int in that order ?

Comment: @nathan Any/AnyObject don't conform to the Codable protocol, so that won't really help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain your case is similar to a question I recently posted: [Flattening JSON when keys are known only at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666668/flattening-json-when-keys-are-known-only-at-runtime).

If so, you could use the following solution:

```
struct MyJSONData: Decodable {
    var dates = [Any]()

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

        // Only use first item
        let stringItem = try container.decode(String.self)
        dates.append(stringItem)
        let numberItem = try container.decode(Int.self)
        dates.append(numberItem)
    }
}

let decoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String : [MyJSONData]].self, from: jsonData).values
// Returns an Array of MyJSONData
```

Working solution: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59949d74677f2b7ec84046c8

Answer (score 1):

I was working with an API which encoded JSON array with heterogeneous data like yours, but even the order of the columns was not know before hand :(

In general, I strongly recommend against storing data in heterogeneous arrays. You will very quickly forget what index stands for what property, not to mention the constant cast back and forth. Instead, make a data model to store it when you decode from the array.

Another thing to note is that your date isn't what `JSONDecoder` expects by default. It expects ISO 8601 format (`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`) whereas the time component is missing from your date string. You can tell `JSONDecoder` what to do by supplying a custom `DateFormatter`:

```
struct WordData: Decodable {
    var date: Date
    var anInt: Int

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        self.date = try container.decode(Date.self)
        self.anInt = try container.decode(Int.self)
    }
}

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_us_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

let words = try decoder.decode([String: [WordData]].self, from: jsonData)
```