# How to extract data from nested JSON with Swift 4 with dynamic keys

Tags: json, swift4

I have a JSON data structure using unique keys that are created on upload. I can read all of it if I read each dictionary item line by line. However, I'm trying to modify my code to use the Swift 4 codable properties.

Doing the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/119922/swift-tutorial-initialization-part-1) and reading the [Ultimate Guide to JSON Parsing with Swift](http://benscheirman.com/2017/06/ultimate-guide-to-json-parsing-with-swift-4/) unfortunately did not propel me to genius status.

The JSON looks like this simple example: 
NOTE that keys, like "123", "456", "case1", "case2", "u1", "u2" are not known at run time.

```
   let json = """
    {
    "things" : {
        "123" : {
        "name" : "Party",
        "owner" : "Bob",
        "isActive" : true,
        "cases" : {
            "case1" : {
                "no" : 1
            },
            "case2" : {
                "no" : 2
            }
        }
        },
        "456" : {
        "name" : "Bus",
        "owner" : "Joe",
        "isActive" : true
        }
    },
    "users" : {
        "u1" : {
        "name" : "Summer"
        },
        "u2" : {
        "name" : "Daffy"
        }
    }
    }
    """
```

Following [this SO question on flattening JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666668/flattening-json-when-keys-are-known-only-at-runtime), I was able to create a decoder for most of my data, but not for the nested dictionaries (in the example, cases is acting like a nested dictionary). I am sure that I am missing something simple.

If I attempt to include the commented out portion, the playground will not run, no error is given.

```
    struct Thing: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let isActive: Bool
    let name: String
    let owner: String
    //var cases = [Case]()

    init(id: String, isActive: Bool, name: String, owner: String){//}, cases: [Case]?) {
        self.id = id
        self.isActive = isActive
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        //self.cases = cases ?? [Case(id: "none", caseNumber: 0)]
    }
}
struct User: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}
struct Case: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let caseNumber: Int
}
struct ResponseData: Decodable {
    var things = [Thing]()
    var users = [User]()


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case trips
        case users
    }

    private struct PhantomKeys: CodingKey {
        var intValue: Int?
        var stringValue: String
        init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue; self.stringValue = "\(intValue)" }
        init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    }

    private enum ThingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isActive, name, owner, cases
    }
    private enum UserKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }
    private enum CaseKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case caseNumber = "no"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let outer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let thingcontainer = try outer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: PhantomKeys.self, forKey: .things)

        for key in thingcontainer.allKeys {
            let aux = try thingcontainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ThingKeys.self, forKey: key)

            let name = try aux.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
            let owner = try aux.decode(String.self, forKey: .owner)
            let isActive = try aux.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isActive)
//            let c = try aux.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CaseKeys.self, forKey: .cases)
//            var cases = [Case]()
//            for ckey in c.allKeys {
//                let caseNumber = try c.decode(Int.self, forKey: .caseNumber)
//                let thiscase = Case(id: ckey.stringValue, caseNumber: caseNumber)
//                cases.append(thiscase)
//            }

            let thing = Thing(id: key.stringValue, isActive: isActive, name: name, owner: owner)//, cases: cases)
            things.append(thing)
        }
        let usercontainer = try outer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: PhantomKeys.self, forKey: .users)

        for key in usercontainer.allKeys {
            let aux = try usercontainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: UserKeys.self, forKey: key)
            let name = try aux.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
            let user = User(id: key.stringValue,name: name)
            users.append(user)
        }
    }
}
```

It works for the things and users, but I have to ignore the cases. See the output of print in comments//.

```
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
let things = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseData.self, from: data).things
print(things[0])
//Thing(id: "456", isActive: true, name: "Bus", owner: "Joe")

let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseData.self, from: data).users
print(users[0])
//User(id: "u1", name: "Summer")
```

I have tried to use the guidance from [this SO question on decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549310/how-to-decode-a-nested-json-struct-with-swift-decodable-protocol) that seems much cleaner to me, but I have not successfully implemented it.

This code is [also a GIST](https://gist.github.com/monkeywithacupcake/ab1a204f12186a11b28d8554b287cde0)

My question is twofold:

1. How can I get the Case data as a nested array in my Thing?
2. Can you
   suggest a cleaner/shorter way to code this? It feels like I'm
   repeating things, but I have seen this kind of wrapper structure in
   several examples for JSON encoding/decoding.

Comment: you cannot encode / decode values automatically for _dynamic keys_ at the very moment in Swift via [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) protocol – such job requires to be done manually.

Comment: I am able to do this with the dynamic keys - see above. "123" and "456" are dynamic keys that I do not know when I get the data. It works through the "PhantomKeys" - I am doing it manually, I guess. However, I still can't get at the nested "cases", which I don't think is impossible.

Comment: see my answer below, i reused your "PhantomKeys" to create an optional list of cases within your "Thing" - i initialy missunderstood your question, hence the edit, i left the original response there just for the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
let data = jsonData.data(using: .utf8)
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
let things = json["things"] as! [String:Any]

for (thing_key, thing_value)   in things as [String:Any] {

    let thing = thing_value as! [String:Any]
    if let cases = thing["cases"] as? [String:Any]{
        for (case_key, case_value) in cases {
            print(case_key)
            print(case_value)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I initially missunderstood your question , here is your code improved to obtain the cases. It was a quick job so might not be optimal, but you get the idea:

```
struct Thing: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let isActive: Bool
    let name: String
    let owner: String
    var cases: [Case]?

    init(id: String, isActive: Bool, name: String, owner: String , cases: [Case]?) {
        self.id = id
        self.isActive = isActive
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        self.cases = cases

    }
}
struct User: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}
struct Case: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let caseNumber: Int
}
struct ResponseData: Decodable {
    var things = [Thing]()
    var users = [User]()


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case things
        case users
        case cases
    }

    private struct PhantomKeys: CodingKey {
        var intValue: Int?
        var stringValue: String
        init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue; self.stringValue = "\(intValue)" }
        init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    }

    private enum ThingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isActive, name, owner, cases
    }
    private enum UserKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }
    private enum CaseKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case no
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let outer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let thingcontainer = try outer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: PhantomKeys.self, forKey: .things)

        for key in thingcontainer.allKeys {
            let aux = try thingcontainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ThingKeys.self, forKey: key)

            let name = try aux.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
            let owner = try aux.decode(String.self, forKey: .owner)
            let isActive = try aux.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isActive)


            var cases:[Case]? = []
            do{
                let casescontainer = try aux.nestedContainer(keyedBy: PhantomKeys.self, forKey: .cases)
                    for case_key in casescontainer.allKeys{

                        let caseaux = try casescontainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CaseKeys.self, forKey: case_key)
                        let no = try caseaux.decode(Int.self, forKey: .no)
                        let thingCase = Case(id:case_key.stringValue, caseNumber: no)
                        cases?.append(thingCase)
                }

            }catch{ }


            let thing = Thing(id: key.stringValue, isActive: isActive, name: name, owner: owner , cases: cases)
            things.append(thing)
        }
        let usercontainer = try outer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: PhantomKeys.self, forKey: .users)

        for key in usercontainer.allKeys {
            let aux = try usercontainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: UserKeys.self, forKey: key)
            let name = try aux.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
            let user = User(id: key.stringValue,name: name)
            users.append(user)
        }
    }
}
```

This produce this output:

```
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
let things = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseData.self, from: data).things
print("-----")
for thing in things{
    print(thing)
}
print("---")
let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseData.self, from: data).users
for user in users{
    print(user)
}
```

---

```
-----
Thing(id: "456", isActive: true, name: "Bus", owner: "Joe", cases: Optional([]))
Thing(id: "123", isActive: true, name: "Party", owner: "Bob", cases: Optional([__lldb_expr_283.Case(id: "case1", caseNumber: 1), __lldb_expr_283.Case(id: "case2", caseNumber: 2)]))
---
User(id: "u1", name: "Summer")
User(id: "u2", name: "Daffy")
```

Comment: sorry for the million edits, took me a while to get there :)

Comment: Oh my goodness. Of course, I would need to use the Phantom Keys again because cases has unknown ids just like things and users. Thank you for working through the problem @mike_t.

Answer (score 0):

You can get keys from your current json as

```
 jq -r 'keys[]'
```

After that query in the loop by each key retrieved

Comment: Can you use `jq` in swift?