# Swift 4 JSON decode with configurable keys

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm new to Swift and I need to parse a JSON with some ***configurable keys***.
Opposite to many examples I've seen here, the keys are known **before** the decode operation is started, they just depend on some parameters passed to endpoint.

Example:

```
https://some.provider.com/endpoint/?param=XXX
```

and

```
https://some.provider.com/endpoint/?param=YYY
```

will answer, respectively:

```
[
    {
        "fixed_key1": "value1",
        "fixed_key2": "value2",
        "variable_key_1_XXX": "some value",
        "variable_key_2_XXX": "some other value"
    },
    ...
]
```

and

```
[
    {
        "fixed_key1": "value1",
        "fixed_key2": "value2",
        "variable_key_1_YYY": "some value",
        "variable_key_2_YYY": "some other value"
    },
    ...
]
```

Given that those keys are known *before decoding*, I was hoping to get away with some clever declaration of a *Decodable* structure and/or *CodingKeys*, without the need to write the

```
init(from decoder: Decoder)
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to come up with such a declaration.

Of course I don't want to write one Decodable/CodingKeys structure for every possible parameter value :-)

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flattening JSON when keys are known only at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666668/flattening-json-when-keys-are-known-only-at-runtime)

Comment: Not exactly the same but pretty much. The proposed solutions will work with your data. (btw jeys should be `fixed_key1` & `fixed_key2`)

Comment: Hi nathan. thanks for highlighting the typo on fixed_key1 and 2. Edited now. About the proposed solution in your link, it doesn't look right. In that case you are discarding the phantom (variable keys), while i want to keep them, so they need to be in my struct. Tried to adapt y code anyway but when trying to decode i got the Type mismatch exception "type = Dictionary<String, Any>, context = Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil)". both if i have the keys in my struct (as optional String) or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless all your JSON keys are compile-time constants, the compiler can't synthesize the decoding methods. But there are a few things you can do to make manual decoding a lot less cumbersome.

First, some helper structs and extensions:

```
/*
Allow us to initialize a `CodingUserInfoKey` with a `String` so that we can write:
    decoder.userInfo = ["param": "XXX"]

Instead of:
    decoder.userInfo = [CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue:"param")!: "XXX"]
*/
extension CodingUserInfoKey: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public typealias StringLiteralType = String

    public init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self.rawValue = value
    }
}

/*
This struct is a plain-vanilla implementation of the `CodingKey` protocol. Adding
`ExpressibleByStringLiteral` allows us to initialize a new instance of
`GenericCodingKeys` with a `String` literal, for example:
    try container.decode(String.self, forKey: "fixed_key1")

Instead of:
    try container.decode(String.self, forKey: GenericCodingKeys(stringValue: "fixed_key1")!)
*/
struct GenericCodingKeys: CodingKey, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    // MARK: CodingKey
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?

    init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }

    // MARK: ExpressibleByStringLiteral
    typealias StringLiteralType = String
    init(stringLiteral: StringLiteralType) { self.stringValue = stringLiteral }
}
```

Then the manual decoding:

```
struct MyDataModel: Decodable {
    var fixedKey1: String
    var fixedKey2: String
    var variableKey1: String
    var variableKey2: String

    enum DecodingError: Error {
        case missingParamKey
        case unrecognizedParamValue(String)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: GenericCodingKeys.self)

        // Decode the fixed keys
        self.fixedKey1 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: "fixed_key1")
        self.fixedKey2 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: "fixed_key2")

        // Now decode the variable keys
        guard let paramValue = decoder.userInfo["param"] as? String else {
            throw DecodingError.missingParamKey
        }

        switch paramValue {
        case "XXX":
            self.variableKey1 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: "variable_key_1_XXX")
            self.variableKey2 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: "variable_key_2_XXX")
        case "YYY":
            self.variableKey1 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: "variable_key_1_YYY")
            self.variableKey2 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: "variable_key_2_YYY")
        default:
            throw DecodingError.unrecognizedParamValue(paramValue)
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here's how you use it:

```
let jsonData = """
[
    {
        "fixed_key1": "value1",
        "fixed_key2": "value2",
        "variable_key_1_XXX": "some value",
        "variable_key_2_XXX": "some other value"
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

// Supplying the `userInfo` dictionary is how you "configure" the JSON-decoding 
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.userInfo = ["param": "XXX"]
let model = try decoder.decode([MyDataModel].self, from: jsonData)

print(model)
```

Comment: Hi Code Different, I just solved using/adaptng your code from [Swift 4 Decodable with keys not known until decoding time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598461/swift-4-decodable-with-keys-not-known-until-decoding-time). Your answer here however, looks more elegant. Guess the topic is hot and answers are evolving/improving. Thank you very much!

Comment: After answering the other question, I actually kept `GenericCodingKeys` as a snippet in Xcode and kept improving on it. That's how it arrived at where it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a similar approach to [@Code Different's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48842316/2976878), you can pass the given parameter information through the decoder's `userInfo` dictionary, and then pass this onto the key type that you use to decode from the keyed container.

First, we can define a new static member on `CodingUserInfoKey` to use as the key in the `userInfo` dictionary:

```
extension CodingUserInfoKey {
  static let endPointParameter = CodingUserInfoKey(
    rawValue: "com.yourapp.endPointParameter"
  )!
}
```

(the force unwrap never fails; I regard the fact the initialiser is failable [as a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6753)).

Then we can define a type for your endpoint parameter, again using static members to abstract away the underlying strings:

```
// You'll probably want to rename this to something more appropriate for your use case
// (same for the .endPointParameter CodingUserInfoKey).
struct EndpointParameter {

  static let xxx = EndpointParameter("XXX")
  static let yyy = EndpointParameter("YYY")
  // ...

  var stringValue: String
  init(_ stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
}
```

Then we can define your data model type:

```
struct MyDataModel {
  var fixedKey1: String
  var fixedKey2: String
  var variableKey1: String
  var variableKey2: String
}
```

And then make it `Decodable` like so:

```
extension MyDataModel : Decodable {

  private struct CodingKeys : CodingKey {
    static let fixedKey1 = CodingKeys("fixed_key1")
    static let fixedKey2 = CodingKeys("fixed_key2")

    static func variableKey1(_ param: EndpointParameter) -> CodingKeys {
      return CodingKeys("variable_key_1_\(param.stringValue)")
    }
    static func variableKey2(_ param: EndpointParameter) -> CodingKeys {
      return CodingKeys("variable_key_2_\(param.stringValue)")
    }

    // We're decoding an object, so only accept String keys.
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int? { return nil }
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
    init(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    init(_ stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    guard let param = decoder.userInfo[.endPointParameter] as? EndpointParameter else {
      // Feel free to make this a more detailed error.
      struct EndpointParameterNotSetError : Error {}
      throw EndpointParameterNotSetError()
    }

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    self.fixedKey1 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .fixedKey1)
    self.fixedKey2 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .fixedKey2)
    self.variableKey1 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .variableKey1(param))
    self.variableKey2 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .variableKey2(param))
  }
}
```

You can see we're defining the fixed keys using static properties on `CodingKeys`, and for the variable keys we're using static methods that take the given parameter as an argument.

Now you can perform a decode like so:

```
let jsonString = """
[
  {
    "fixed_key1": "value1",
    "fixed_key2": "value2",
    "variable_key_1_XXX": "some value",
    "variable_key_2_XXX": "some other value"
  }
]
"""

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.userInfo[.endPointParameter] = EndpointParameter.xxx
do {
  let model = try decoder.decode([MyDataModel].self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
  print(model)
} catch {
  print(error)
}

// [MyDataModel(fixedKey1: "foo", fixedKey2: "bar",
//              variableKey1: "baz", variableKey2: "qux")]
```

Comment: Also great!. thank you Hamish. I don't particularly like the definition of **EndpointParameter** struct since the parameter can assume _many_ values, but this can easily be adapted.

Comment: @MarcoD. Sure, you didn't show your concrete use case so it was a bit of a guess; the main point I was making was the use of strong types rather than strings. Glad it was useful :)